# chrome.tabs.query currentWindow on "inactive" background page doesn't return tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a background page that's configured as `persistent: false` in the `manifest.json`.

The background page implements the following Chrome API method:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    // tabs is empty
});
```

If the background page becomes inactive when the above code is called, the `query` method returns no tabs in the callback, removing the `currentWindow` filter returns tabs but not for all windows. Using `lastFocusedWindow` doesn't work either.

Is there a way to make the inactive background page successfully query the current window active tab.

Comment: Sounds like a bug or there's probably something else in your code that's messing up the results.

Answer (score 0):

It's a side effect of memory offloading. Consider using [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage), which will ensure the event page is fully loaded prior to invoking the callback.

From developer.chrome.com:

`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function callback)`

> Retrieves the JavaScript 'window' object for the background page running inside the current extension/app. If the background page is an event page, the system will ensure it is loaded before calling the callback. If there is no background page, an error is set.

Comment: I tried wrapping my `chrome.tabs.query` inside a `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` callback call, but still is returning no tabs. Could be that `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` must be called before invoking the functions on the background page instead inside itself?

Comment: @jonathanwiesel, no, it's not required. This answer is not relevant because your code runs, only the results are incorrect. Like I said, the behavior you described sounds like a bug.

Comment: @jonathanwiesel Perhaps @wOxxOm is correct, but I would try debugging before chalking this up as a bug. It sounds like a side effect of the newer autodiscard features Chrome has implemented. If you use `chrome.windows.getAll` and set `populate` to `true`, that should give you an array of window objects, each containing a property with their subsequent tabs. I would test that out and see if you're still getting incomplete results.